# Polymer access elements within vaadin-grid

Tags: polymer, vaadin

Working jsbin illustrating the problem: http://jsbin.com/nomewa/3/edit?html,console,output

I am trying to set the innerHTML of `notworking` span inside of a template that makes up the `vaadin-grid`. It does not currently seems to be possible to bind to `on-change` of `vaadin-checkbox` when said `vaadin-checkbox` lies within `vaadin-grid` since I cannot even access the element within the grid.

Comment: I would start by using a stable vaadin-grid version. 2.0.3 should be the latest for Polymer 1 (it’s better to use that instead of the hybrid v3, better performance I’ve understood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great way to try some codes (jsbin :)  Here this code works but I do not know is it going to fit your need. (I cut and copied only changed parts :
At the property declaration, you may set a pre-value to `notWorking` property. Then you may change it with dynamically in a function.

```
<iron-ajax url="https://randomuser.me/api?results=10" last-response="{{response}}" auto></iron-ajax>
    <span id="working">Working</span>
    <vaadin-grid id="grid" items="{{response.results}}" style="height: auto;">
      <vaadin-grid-column>
        <template class="header">Name</template>
        <template>[[item.name.first]] [[item.name.last]] <span>{{notWorking}}</span></template>
      </vaadin-grid-column>
    </vaadin-grid>
  </template>
  <script>
    class MyTest extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'test-component'; }

      ready() {
        super.ready();
        this.set('notWorking',"test")
        debugger;
      }
    }
```

Here the working [link](http://jsbin.com/vapayir/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, my current issue is that I cannot bind to an `on-changed` event of a `vaadin-checkbox` in each row. Your solution isn't applicable in my case. I have built a somewhat dirty fix where there is 1 `vaadin-checkbox` and 1 `input` `type="checkbox"` per template, the `on-click` event on `vaadin-checkbox` binds it's input to the hidden input (and triggers the inputs `on-changed`).

Answer (score 1):

> It does not currently seems to be possible to bind to on-change of vaadin-checkbox when said vaadin-checkbox lies within vaadin-grid since I cannot even access the element within the grid.

You can use declarative event bindings inside the column tempates, so you don’t have to have a reference to the actual stamped element.

Something like this:

```
<vaadin-grid-column>
  <template>
    <vaadin-checkbox on-checked-changed="_myListener">Checkbox</vaadin-checkbo>
  </template>
</vaadin-grid-colum>
```

Comment: I am well aware of the fact that I can use declarative event bindings inside column templates, this is what my (somewhat) rough fix below depends on. However I am looking for a practical example (e.g. a working jsbin) without rewriting `vaadin-checkbox`, this is only possible with my fix so far.